# Javascript tool/website for sharing scripts and developing

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a website/service were I can develop and share my Javascript code with others. I had a site open in browser the other which did it nicely, but after searching my history and googling around for half an hour, I can't find anything.

The site I saw was split into four areas: html, css, javascript and result..

Anybody know a site like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**JSFiddle** is what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Note that at times when JSFiddle is slow, you might want to use [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/).